# Find the percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query that I should translate into SQL that says:
Retrieve the percentage of doctors who are specialized in Cardiology
Below is the Doctor table:
[image]

So there are 2 doctors out of 5 that have a specialization in cardiology and the result must be 40%.
Can you help me write the query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when specialization = 'Cardiologist' then 1.0 else 0 end) as card_ratio
from doctors;
```

If you want a value between 0 and 100, use `100.0` instead of `1.0`.